# How to close a Slidable from outside its widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using the package `flutter_slidable`, which is amazing to get extra functionalities in list items. However, I still can't figure out how to control a `Slidable` widget from outside its tree.

**Simple App:**

I have a `ListView` and each one of its items is wrapped with a `Slidable`. These tiles are composed by a `TextFormField`. I would like to be able to close a Slidable by tapping another tile. To be more precise, by tapping the TextFormField of another tile.

There are three tiles with Slidables attached to them.

In the following images, from left to right:

1. I slide the second tile.
2. I tap the `TextFormField` of the third tile.
3. Then, the `Slidable` of the second tile **should be closed**.

[image]

**Main Page:**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            title: const Text('Slidable from outside'),
        ),
        body: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
          closeWhenOpened: true,
          closeWhenTapped: false,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return const MyTile();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Tile:**

```
class MyTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      closeOnScroll: false,
      startActionPane: const ActionPane(
        dragDismissible: false,
        motion: ScrollMotion(),
        children: [
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
            icon: Icons.remove_circle_outline_outlined,
            autoClose: false,
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          SlidableAction(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFe0e0e0),
            icon: Icons.add_circle_outline_outlined,
            autoClose: false,
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        child: TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
            color: Colors.grey[800],
          ),
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            isDense: true,
            border: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          ),
          initialValue: '25.000',
          onTap: () {
            //Some code that triggers the close action of another Slidable
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

From what I understand, in old versions of this package you used a `SlidableController`, but it has changed now. A recommended way is to wrap the list with a `SlidableAutoCloseBehavior`, but it can't control each Slidable independently.

The parameter `closeWhenTapped` is the closest to a solution because if I set this to `true`, it let me close the tile after tapping in another tile, **but, I have to tap twice**, hence the TextFormField is not selectable at first touch. So I set it to `false` in order to let me select the TextFormField although without being able to close the Slidable automatically.

Answer (score -1):

SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
child: ListView(
children: [
Slidable(
groupTag: '0',
),
Slidable(
groupTag: '0',
),
Slidable(
groupTag: '1',
),
],
),
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).